# logstash target of repeat operator is not specified:

Tags: regex, logstash

I want to use logstash to ship my logs,so I download the logstash1.5.0 rc2 and run it in ubuntu use the command :

```
 bin/logstash -f test.conf
```

then the console show the error:

```
The error reported is: 
  **target of repeat operator is not specified:** /;(?<Args:method>*);(?<INT:traceid:int>(?:[+-]?(?:[0-9]+)));(?<INT:sTime:int>(?:[+-]?(?:[0-9]+)));(?<INT:eTime:int>(?:[+-]?(?:[0-9]+)));(?<HOSTNAME:hostname>\b(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62})(?:\.(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}))*(\.?|\b));(?<INT:eoi:int>(?:[+-]?(?:[0-9]+)));(?<INT:ess:int>(?:[+-]?(?:[0-9]+)));(?<Args:args>*)/m
```

I don't know how to solve this error,may be you can help me.

my test.conf is as follow:

```
input { stdin { } }

filter {
grok {
match => ["message" , "%{INT:type}"]}


if [type]=="10" {
grok {
patterns_dir => "./patterns"
match => ["message" , ";%{Args:method};%{INT:traceid:int};%{INT:sTime:int};%{INT:eTime:int};%{HOSTNAME:hostname};%{INT:eoi:int};%{INT:ess:int};%{Args:args}"]
}

date {
    match => [ "sTime" , "UNIX_MS" ]
  }
ruby {
code => "event['duration'] = event['eTime'] - event['sTime']"
}

}
if [type] =~ /3[1-6]/ {
  grok {
patterns_dir => "./patterns"
  match => [ "message" , ";%{Args:method};%{Args:sessionid};%{INT:traceID:int};%{INT:sTime:int};%{INT:eTime:int};%{HOSTNAME:hostname};%{INT:eoi:int};%{INT:ess:int};URL{%{HttpField:url}};RequestHeader{%{HttpField:ReqHeader}};RequestPara{%{HttpField:ReqPara}};RequestAttr{%{HttpField:ReqAttr}};SessionAttr{%{HttpField:SessionAttr}};ResponseHeader{%{HttpField:ResHeader}}"]
  }
 kv {
source => "ReqHeader"
    field_split => ";"
        value_split => ":"
target => "ReqHeader"
 }
 kv {
source => "ResHeader"
    field_split => ";"
        value_split => ":"
target => "ResHeader"
  }
date {
    match => [ "sTime" , "UNIX_MS" ]
  }
ruby {
code => "event['duration'] = event['eTime'] - event['sTime']"
}
}
if [type] == "30" {
  grok {
patterns_dir => "./patterns"
  match => [ "message" ,";%{Args:method};%{Args:sessionid};%{INT:traceID:int};%{INT:sTime:int};%{INT:eTime:int};%{HOSTNAME:hostname};%{INT:eoi:int};%{INT:ess:int};URL{%{HttpField:url}};RequestHeader{%{HttpField:ReqHeader}};RequestPara{%{HttpField:ReqPara}};RequestAttr{%{HttpField:ReqAttr}};SessionAttr{%{HttpField:SessionAttr}}"
  ]
  }
 kv {
source => "ReqHeader"
    field_split => ";"
        value_split => ":"
target => "ReqHeader"
 }
 kv {
source => "ResHeader"
    field_split => ";"
        value_split => ":"
target => "ResHeader"
  }
date {
    match => [ "sTime" , "UNIX_MS" ]
  }
ruby {
code => "event['duration'] = event['eTime'] - event['sTime']"
}
}

if [type]=="20" {
grok {
patterns_dir => "./patterns"
match => [ "message" , ";%{Args:method};%{INT:traceID:int};%{INT:sTime:int};%{INT:eTime:int};%{HOSTNAME:hostname};%{INT:eoi:int};%{INT:ess:int};%{INT:mtype};%{Args:DBUrl}"]
}
date {
    match => [ "sTime" , "UNIX_MS" ]
  }
ruby {
code => "event['duration'] = event['eTime'] - event['sTime']"
}
}
if [type]=="21" {
grok {
patterns_dir => "./patterns"
match => [ "message" , ";%{Args:method};%{INT:traceID:int};%{INT:sTime:int};%{INT:eTime:int};%{HOSTNAME:hostname};%{INT:eoi:int};%{INT:ess:int};%{INT:mtype};%{Args:sql};%{Args:bindVariables}"]
}
date {
    match => [ "sTime" , "UNIX_MS" ]
  }
ruby {
code => "event['duration'] = event['eTime'] - event['sTime']"
}
}
if [type]=="12" {
grok {
patterns_dir => "./patterns"
match => [ "message" , ";%{Args:method};%{INT:traceID:int};%{INT:sTime:int};%{INT:eTime:int};%{HOSTNAME:hostname};%{INT:eoi:int};%{INT:ess:int};%{Args:logStack}"]
}
date {
    match => [ "sTime" , "UNIX_MS" ]
  }
ruby {
code => "event['duration'] = event['eTime'] - event['sTime']"
}
}
if [type]=="11" {
grok {
patterns_dir => "./patterns"
match => [ "message" , ";%{Args:method};%{INT:traceID};%{INT:sTime:int};%{INT:eTime:int};%{HOSTNAME:hostname};%{INT:eoi:int};%{INT:ess:int};%{Args:errorStack}"]
}
date {
    match => [ "sTime" , "UNIX_MS" ]
  }
ruby {
code => "event['duration'] = event['eTime'] - event['sTime']"
}
}


if [type]=="50" {
grok {
patterns_dir => "./patterns"
match => [ "message" , ";%{INT:sTime:int};%{HOSTNAME:host};%{Args:JVMName};%{Args:GCName};%{INT:count:int};%{INT:time:int}"]
}
date {
    match => [ "sTime" , "UNIX_MS" ]
  }
}
if [type]=="51" {
grok {
patterns_dir => "./patterns"
match => [ "message" , ";%{INT:sTime:int};%{HOSTNAME:host};%{Args:JVMName};%{INT:maxheap};%{INT:currentheap};%{INT:commitheap};%{INT:iniheap};%{INT:maxnonheap};%{INT:currentnonheap};%{INT:commitnonheap};%{INT:ininonheap}"]
}
date {
    match => [ "sTime" , "UNIX_MS" ]
  }
} 
if [type]=="52" {
grok {
patterns_dir => "./patterns"
match => [ "message" , ";%{INT:sTime:int};%{HOSTNAME:host};%{Args:JVMName};%{Args:iniloadedclasses};%{Args:currentloadedclasses};%{Args:iniunloadedclasses}"]
}
date {
    match => [ "sTime" , "UNIX_MS" ]
  }
}
}


output {
  elasticsearch { host => "127.2.96.1"
       protocol => "http"
       port => "8080" }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug
}
}
```

Comment: The regular expression that it complains about doesn't match the first grok plugin in your configuration file. Are you sure you pasted the correct file? But judging by the error message the problem appears to be that you have a `*` near the end of the expression but no token that precedes it (`(?<Args:args>*)`). Perhaps you meant `.*`?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have repair this problem. The problem is because I lost a space in the file which define the 'Args ' pattern.    Thanks very much!